# Proof using the Lambert W function that 1 = 0 - What went wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, lambert-w

All values that satisfy $x^2=2^x$ would satisfy $\ln(2)x^3 = x\ln(2)e^{x\ln(2)}$, and would therefore satisfy the relationship $W(\ln(2)x^3) = x\ln(2)$. The problem is that when I graph these functions, there are four real solutions to this relation: $x \approx -0.77$, and $x=4, 2, 0$. The first three are solutions to $2^x=x^2$, but $0$ is not. So what happened?

Comment: It looks like you multiplied by $x$, and if $x=0$ that's a problem.  For instance, $1=2$ is false, but if I multiply both sides by $0$ I get $0=0$ which is true.

Comment: When you multiplied by $x$ you introduced the extraneous solution of $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^2 =2^x
$$
$$
2\ln(x)=x\ln(2)
$$
**Note that $x \neq 0 $**, since $\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x) = -\infty$

So you accidentally introduced a extraneous solution.
It is much like the classic proof:

$$
a =b
$$
$$a^2 = ab$$
$$a^2-b^2 = ab - b^2$$
$$ (a-b)(a+b) =  b(a-b)$$
$$a+b = b$$
But $b=a$
$$2b = b$$
$$2=1$$
$$\forall a \& b \neq 0$$

With the mistake being that we can't divide by $(a-b)$, since $a-b = 0$

Comment: In your example $2b=b$ does not imply $2=1$ because we divide by $b$ which might be $0$. But we can easily repair the fake-proof by assuming $b\ne 0$ at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use your technique to solve $3x=6$.  We will first multiply by $x$ [this is the "mistake"] to get $3x^2=6x$.  Subtracting and factoring gives $3x(x-2)=0$, which has the two solutions $x=0$ and $x=2$.  Of these, only the second is a solution to our original equation.  The "solution" $x=0$ is extraneous/false because multiplying any equation $A=B$ at all by $0$ on both sides results in something true (namely $0=0$) whether or not $A=B$ is true.